# Web Page Autofill in Visual Basic Script

Tags: vbscript

I am using Visual Basic Script to autofill a box titled:

id='V_RUN_PA100A_BUSINESS_UNIT' (I got this from the page source)

I used the code

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate("https://jayfin.cov.kansas.gov/psp/finprd/?cmd=login&languageCd=ENG")
ie.visible = 1
ie.document.all.item("V_RUN_PA100A_BUSINESS_UNIT").Value = "40400"
```

I keep getting the error `..object required`

Based on what I understand, the fact that the ID of the box is in single quotes instead of double quotes is the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you use the element ID to set the value?

```
ie.document.getElementById("V_RUN_PA100A_BUSINESS_UNIT").Value = "40400"
```

The double/single quote is not an issue. In javascript/html you can use both, VBScript only uses double quotes but they are both way interchangeable.